# Can Matrices exist on vertex registers other than vertex constants in AGAL?

Tags: flash, matrix, vertex-shader, stage3d, agal

I've mostly seen examples where a **Matrix3D** object is passed as a vertex constant register in AS3 to the **Context3D** object. But never seen a matrix in any other types of registers (***temporary*** or ***attribute***).

Would there be any way to copy a Matrix vertex constant to a temporary register, and then manipulate individual fields of that Matrix temporary register (ex:for the rotation), with other supplied values (vertex attributes or other constants)?

Could a simple `mov dest, source` operation do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works (take it from the Mole :)). Just make sure to copy enough (3 or 4) registers. Also a good way to think about matrix operations is that they are just a shortcut for 3 or 4 dot product instructions. There is really nothing typed in AGAL, a matrix is just a few consecutive registers. The matrix upload functions are only convenience for uploading to 4 registers in one call. And in the shader

`m44 dest, src, srcmatrix`

is the exact same as:

```
dp4 dest.x srx, srcmatrix  
dp4 dest.y srx, srcmatrix+1  
dp4 dest.z srx, srcmatrix+2  
dp4 dest.w srx, srcmatrix+3
```

The +1 etc here means register number +1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain temporary registers also contain Matrices and that your request is possible, but you may get your best answer from someone like Marco Scabia:

http://iflash3d.com/

He's very approachable and knowledgeable of AGAL.

Comment: Nice! This will probably help me for more AGAL questions I'll have in the future!

Comment: I'm glad :) I know how hard good AGAL resources are to come by.  Good luck!